# App crashes on iOS (Phonegap) if multiple images are captured from camera

Tags: objective-c, cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am developing Phonegap Application and my application has scenarios where camera is used very frequently.

In my application I have used custom camera plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-camera-custom) to take picture and use it in my application.

Now when I capture images from this camera 30 times by opening camera and capturing again and again the app goes to crash.

The app just crashes so I am not able to identify the root cause of the crash.

I am not an iOS Programmer though I have tried to check the plugin code but I was not able to find the cause.

You can even check the plugin code on your end if needed.

I have also posted this issue to DevExtreme, the framework which I am using to develop hybrid applications at following link:

https://www.devexpress.com/support/center/Question/Details/T480068

and they found that issue indeed is related to memory shortage. The error message was with **bug_type: 298** and **fault cause: vm_pageshortage**.

Please help me on this, I am struggling on it since long before.

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try giving storage permission to the application.

Comment: @AkashKR I think this is not an issue of storage permissions because the crash occurs on multiple capture of images from camera.

As I have mentioned I am capturing images 30 times in a row and almost on 31st capture App crashes